# Download APK from remote server. Link on Push Notification

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, push-notification

We have configured many devices (more than 200) with only one Google account. Two weeks ago, this account was hacked and we had to change the password.

Now, to solve this issue, we need an alternative for not asking the users to change the password. (Many users are basic users and they don't know how to change it).

A possible alternative could be:

All the devices have the same App developed by us with "Push Notifications" functionality.

Is it possible to send a notification with a link to an URL to download a new version of the App from my company server? I have seen an option to include a "click_url" parameter but it requires to implement a custom filter action on AndroidManifest.xml

This alternative needs to be possible with the App installed on devices, not with a new version of it, because we haven't any methods to deploy the new version of the App.

Thank you in advance. Best regards.

Comment: if you have this notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("URL to download new version")); and you can set the url from push notification.

Comment: But only if users allow installation from 'Unknown sources' in settings/security.

Comment: but why you can't deploy a new version? is the hacked email same one used for publishing apps? also you mentioned you have changed the password, i.e you have recovered the email, right?

Answer (score 1):

The account to deploy Apps is different, so the problem and also, we have recover the account, but the users must update Google Account password on their devices. So, we can deploy a new versions but it cannot be installed on the devices. We have a backoffice in PHP, to send push notifications, so we want to send a link inside the push content and if the user touches over the push, it will download a new version from our corporative server. All the devices have "Unknown sources" enabled.

This is the code we have to send push:

```
private function sendPushAndroid($tituloNot, $mensajeNot) {
    // API access key from Google API's Console
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOU_API_KEY' );


    // Capturo todos los id y los meto en un array
    // Intenta la inserción en la BBDD
    try {
        $conn = DbConfig::setUpDatabase ();
        $conn->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $conn->beginTransaction ();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare ( "SELECT deviceID FROM devices WHERE plataforma = 'android';" );
        $stmt->execute ();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll ();

        foreach ( $result as $v ) {
            $registrationIds = array (
                    $v ["deviceID"]
            );
        }

        // var_dump($registrationIds);

        // Do not delete "big_picture_url
        // prep the bundle
        $msg = array (
                'title' => $tituloNot,
                'alert' => $mensajeNot,
                'json' => '{"big_picture_url": "",
                    "string_extra": "100000583627394",
                    "string_value": "value",
                    "string_key": "key",
                    "is_public": true,
                    "item_type_id": 4,
                    "numeric_extra": 0}'
        ); // string_extra?

        $fields = array (
                'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
                'data' => $msg
        );

        $headers = array (
                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        // curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); //not needed, by default it returns true or false.
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode ( $fields ) );
        $sent = curl_exec ( $ch );
        curl_close ( $ch );
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        // echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you will be able to do it with a push notification. We use hockeyapp to release our private build for testers and developers.